# get_current_user_id() returning Zero 0

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

`get_current_user_id()` is returning 0 for following codes. I do tried some solution available on stack overflow but somehow not working for me. I'm expecting explanation why its returning zero and how to fix?

P.S: I'm calling get_current_user_id() from external php page and included `'../wp-blog-header.php'` for that.

Code:

```
<?php
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
get_header();

$user_ID = get_current_user_id(); 
echo $user_ID;

?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to call wordpress proccess of user authentication. Try adding the following code before `get_current_user_id();`, if it doesn't solve your problem it'll at least point you the right direction:

```
$user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
wp_set_current_user( $user_id );
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a result of including `wp-blog-header.php` directly in your external file. From [the Codex on `get_current_user_id()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id):

> The user's ID, if there is a current user; otherwise 0.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the correct method would be to add this logic to *functions.php* under the correct [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), or by [writing a custom plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin). By doing one of those two things, you will have access to the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax then may be in some browser versions we can't get id by get_current_user_id() for this we can use xhrFields in over ajax then it will work fine. if the problem with the browser version.

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            cache: false,
```