# get_current_user_id() returns 0 even after modificaton to user.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I've the following folder structure:

```
root/wordpress/* // all wordpress related files
root/myApp/test.php
```

Under `test.php`, I've the following code

```
<?php
require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
$userid = get_current_user_id();
echo $userid; // prints 0 on the page
?>
```

So to play around and experiment, I went ahead and did the following in `root/wordpress/wp-includes/user.php`

```
function get_current_user_id() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) )
        return 1;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return ( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 2 );
}
```

But the output on `test.php` still prints 0. What am I missing here?

Also

- I'm very well aware one should not directly include `wp-blog-header.php` in an external app and rather should use the recommended approach while passing the user session
- One should not edit the core files

I'll undo them as soon as I figure out why the update in the core file (`user.php`) isn't reflecting the change

FWIW, WP version `4.9.3` is what is being used.

### Update

I'm not really looking for a solution where the user session will be passed onto the external app. Rather, I'm trying to figure out why isn't the edit to `user.php` not taking effect?

Comment: I guess wp-blog-header.php is not sufficient to load wordpress core in an external script. Probably you need to require another wordpress core file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_current\_user\_id() returning Zero 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113060/get-current-user-id-returning-zero-0)

Comment: @GiacomoM But why doesn't my edit on the `user.php` file not taking effect? Behind the scenes, that is what the function executes right?

Comment: @SenrorGui Not really. The linked answer tells me about a working solution. My query here is that why isn't the edit to `user.php` not taking effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
require('../wordpress/wp-load.php');
global $current_user;
echo $current_user->ID;
```

> You need to include wp-load.php file, Then you need to use global
>   $current_user which is for getting the current user data. This is
>   sufficient to print the current user ID.

Comment: Once again, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to figure out why the edit to `user.php` not taking effect?

Comment: @asprin are you sure your code executes the get_current_user_id function? try to put some code block to be sure of that

Comment: Yes, it's executing. Interestingly, it's getting called 4 times...wonder why

Comment: Try to include this file, I faced a similar issue many months ago and the solution was to include the users file (wp-admin/includes/user.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out. It was very silly of me to miss that.

`get_current_user_id()` internally calls `wp_get_current_user()` which has the following line:

```
$user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );
    if ( ! $user_id ) {
        wp_set_current_user( 0 ); // <--- this is the culprit which was setting it to 0
        return $current_user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call wordpress proccess of user authentication. Try adding the following code before `get_current_user_id();`, if it doesn't solve your problem it'll at least point you the right direction:

```
require('../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');

wp_set_current_user(apply_filters('determine_current_user', false));

$userid = get_current_user_id();
echo $userid;
```

EDIT 1:

Get the user ID from `$_SESSION`.
Run `print_r($_SESSION);` to see what your field is.

Comment: Again, I'm not trying to solve the authentication problem. Please read what I'm really looking for