# Get authorized user id on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When trying to get the id of an authorized user wordpress gives 0.

[phpmyadmin screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrlKN.png)

```
<?php

$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];

try {
    require "db_config.php";
    require "wp-includes/user.php";
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

$cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();

$sql = "INSERT INTO events (title, start, cur_user_id) VALUES (:title, :start, :cur_user_id)";
$q = $cal_db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':cur_user_id'=>$cur_user_id));

?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get\_current\_user\_id() returning Zero 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113060/get-current-user-id-returning-zero-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put my code in a new folder in plugins and activated in wordpress, everything worked.
https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: If you have another question open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$cur_user_id = wp_get_current_user();
```

Comment: Nothing happens on localhost, but the error 500 is displayed on the hosting.

Comment: Also try this way

`global $current_user;
wp_get_current_user();
//if you want another thing like his name or any things
print_r($current_user);
//if you want ID
echo $current_user->ID; `